# combining javascript files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have several javascript files and I'd like to combine them into one file but only when the page is rendered, and still keep my files separate because it's easier to code with multiple files than one giant one.

How do I do this? I saw some tutorials on how to do it but they're dated. I'm using VS 2012 and I was wondering if there's a newer way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned VS2012, check [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097384).

Comment: ah yes, that's the feature I was looking for. Where do we put the line BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; ?

Comment: It seems that it should be somewhere in Global.asax, check http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-vnext-videos-bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 1):

Use ScriptManager's thingy called "CompositeScript". Probably the easiest way to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552(v=vs.90).aspx

You can always implement your custom solution though, if this doesn't fit your needs for whatever reason.

Comment: I get 'ScriptManager' is not a known element. I've added the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll file to the bin directory but it's not working. any suggestion?

Comment: ScriptManager is a regular control since version 3.5, you don't need ajaxcontroltoolkit in order to work with it. There's another similar control called ToolkitScriptManager you're probably confusing this one with. Please verify that you have a reference in your project to System.Web.Extensions

Comment: This seems too much trouble; I'm going with the VS2012 bundling option. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Referencing ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll is ok, while referencing a regular .net dll is "too much trouble"? Furthermore, you choose a path using a RC version of .NET framework, where you may encounter problems with availability etc. Well, good luck with that...

Comment: Well I'm looking to avoid dependencies.

Comment: Once again and for the last time - how does using RC version of .net or using an external dll of ajaxcontroltoolkit helps you overcome that? In my opinion, it's far easier to rely on the regular part of .net framework that has been around since 3.5 without the need to include any external files along with your project and without the need to be dependent on some RC version, while it's final version hasn't even been released yet. But hey, that's just me :) Seems you have a different opinion on this matter and it's really getting too late for me.

Comment: Btw, if you're already using ajaxcontroltoolkit, there's ToolkitScriptManager control that provides very similar (sometimes completely equal) functionality, so I really don't see your point.

Comment: ok, let me think about all that; the bundling option isn't working as promised either!